# How to justify and preserve the paragraph spacing at the same time?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,twoside,reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsmath,enumerate,verbatim,calc,graphicx} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\textwidth = 12.5 cm 
\textheight = 20 cm 
\topmargin = 0.5 cm 
\oddsidemargin = 1 cm 
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\evensidemargin = 1 cm 
\pagestyle{plain} 
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
\begingroup
\renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\endgroup
}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\justify
\centering
\title{\textbf{ON THE REFLECTION PROPERTY OF A CIRCULAR PARABOLOID}}
\maketitle
\author{\textbf{S. Aryan}}
\begin{abstract}
 Text for abstract. 
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\justify
 This is the introduction. 
 \end{document}
```

When I run this code. I get the text "This is the introduction" printed without the initial space before the word "This." I want the paragraph to be justified but when I use `\justify` I lose the space before the first word that marks the beginning of a paragraph. Is there a way to resolve this trade-off? In order to make my problem more clearer, I have posted below an image that shows the paragraphs in my actual document.

[image]

I want the word "The" in the image to be shifted to the right to mark the beginning of a paragraph.

Comment: Most of `amsart` users require, that the first paragraph after section, subsection ... titles are not indented.

Comment: I can't remove amsart  because it is the journal's preamble, so what should I do?

Comment: Obey journal rule. If they select `amsart` as document class, that this is desired/requested behavior. All others paragraphs after first after section/subsection .. tiles are indented.

Comment: It should be obvious, that after any kind of section always a new paragraph is starting.  So why would one focus on that fact, by additionally indenting the paragraph?  You only need to indent the second and later paragraphs, as you otherwise don't know, where a paragraph starts.

Comment: See edit of my answer. Some my assumption wasn't correct :(. Package `amsart` make all paragraphs indented, but this rule you override with commands `\centering` and `\justify`.

Comment: if this is for journal submission (or even if it is not!) don't put font changes into structural commands like `\title` and `\author` it means the document won't meet the journal style guidelines and complicates extracting the metadata to put into the various databases of author/title information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
After reexamination of your MWE I observe, that your problem is use of  `\centering` and `\justify` and placing of `\author{...}`. After removing former two commands and moving latter in correct place (before `\maketitle`), your MWE become:

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,twoside,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsmath,enumerate,verbatim,calc,graphicx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\textwidth = 12.5 cm
\textheight = 20 cm
\topmargin = 0.5 cm
\oddsidemargin = 1 cm


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{ON THE REFLECTION PROPERTY OF A CIRCULAR PARABOLOID}}
\author{\textbf{S. Aryan}}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for your answer. I am very grateful for your help.